# How to avoid Authentication issue in Mozilla FF in SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I've deployed an SSRS report on my PC and am able to access my report through the report manager. When I copied the report URL and opened it on another PC over the network, it asked for credentials when using Mozilla Firefox.

I've tried the following in Firefox:

> The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise!, to continue to the about:config page.
>
> In the about:config page, search for the preference network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris, and double-click on it.

I've added my server URL in that manner, which prevents the credentials popup from appearing.

I don't think this is the correct way of doing things. If I'd pass around the URL to -say- 100 different users, they would all need to do what i did as described above?

Can anyone help me to avoid credentials popups (username and password), and open the report directly?

Comment: What you describe _is_ the correct way to do this.

SSRS is secured with Windows integrated authentication. Users need to have credentials to access this and Firefox doesn't try your windows credentials unless you tell it to, with the setting you mention. The setting you mention can be set by a script, maybe run by a GPO.

Comment: @JamieF,thnaks for your reply.for security reasons we cannot specify our internel url in all mozilla  fire fox NTML in my organisation. Is their any alternate solution is available or not?please reply ASAP

Comment: Sounds like you have conflicting requirements: you aren't allowed to have Firefox automatically log in, but you want Firefox to automatically log in. That means this is not a technical problem, but a policy problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report will need credentials to run. (Turning on anonymous access to SSRS is not supported and not recommended.)

Those credentials can come from a few different places.
1. Users are prompted for user name and password.
2. Credentials are stored in the browser (or in Windows.) As you've seen, this is easier to handle with Internet Explorer than Firefox for NTLM authentication. But Firefox does give you an option, as you've mentioned.
3. Some other service or website accesses the report server and hands in credentials. This other service then passes the report on to users. Designing this would require some thought: Would you need to track who accesses this service? How would you secure individual reports?

Your comment suggests that you have conflicting requirements: you aren't allowed to have Firefox automatically log in for security reasons, but you want to have Firefox automatically log in. There's no technical advice that can solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. check your server URL, must be just "http://server_name" in firefox about:config "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" key
2. store credential required in for accessing data source, at report tab "data source"-"Credential stored securely in the report server"
3. add in security tab "domain user" that has credentials for accessing the report , check only for "Browsing"
4. enter credential for "domain user",for the first time when showing report in firefox and allow to remember
5. now it works automatically when you start link shortcut